# How to disable auto tweet for new post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I haven't used any plugin which does auto tweet new posts in my WordPress site still whenever i create new post and publish, it will automatically tweet.  How do I disable this?

Is it possible to disable auto tweet functionality and allow admin to do this auto tweet?

Answer (score 0):

Near the publish button see there will be a 'edit' link for this plugin and it will allow to choose on which social networking platforms you wish to push this post.

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to see any edit link for choosing social networking platform

Answer (score 0):

Got to: Configure > sharing > Connections > publicize your posts > press the disconnect button beside the social network you would like to disable! =]
I hope it works! My first trial will be this week!